# How to manage the list of abbreviations for periodicals?

Tags: biblatex, acronyms

I cite a lot of articles of the same magazine of different years. So I would like to make an abbreviation of this magazine to put in footnotes and in the  list of abbreviations. I mean one shorthand for the all years of the same magazine with only the first year of edition indicated in the list of abbreviations. 
Like this:

> ### Abbreviations
>
> EP - Name of the magazine, 1970-

The articles have no author's name.

For the bib-entries I've made a `xref`, like domwass advised.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress]{biblatex}

\bibliography{master2}

\begin{document}

@Article{Episkepsis1971:36,
title = {La Commission préparatoire },
date = {1971},
number = {36},
pages = {2},
xref = {Episkepsis}
}

@Article{Episkepsis1971:36_2,
title = {Communique de la Commission },
date = {1971},
number = {36},
pages = {8--9},
xref = {Episkepsis}
}

@Article{Episkepsis1972:54,
title = {La première Conférence},
date = {1972},
number = {54},
pages = {2--5},
xref = {Episkepsis}
}

@Collection{Episkepsis,
journal = {Episkepsis},
date = {1970/},
shorthand = {EP},
keywords = {primary},
}


\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources principaux}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword={primary},heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources secondaires}]

\end{document}
```

But when I make `\printshorthands` I get in the list of abbreviations all articles with the same abbriviation like this:

> ### Abbreviations
>
> EP - 1970-.

And it has no abbr. in footnotes (Just number of magazine and the year) and in  bibliography.

Also I'd like to make a space between an abbreviation and it's explanation a little bit more wide.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried to use xref rather than crossref? I don’t know if this helps, but it is worth a try.

Comment: @domwass Thanks. :) It helped a little. Now it shows in the list of abbr. "EP - 1970-." just one time. But there is no magazine name neither in the list of abbr. nor in the footnotes (in footnotes it shows only the number and the year). Maybe I should add some code for declare some details? Would you help me please?

Comment: If you could add a [complete minimal example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html), I can have a look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `shorthand` field will only provide a "short identifier" for a certain bibliographry entry (say, a collection), but it will not use this identifier as an abbreviation in other entries (say, articles) that may be `crossref`ed with the first one. If you're interested to display abbreviated journal titles for articles (but only in citations, not in the bibliography), I suggest the following:

- To correctly display the title of the `@collection` entry, change the `journaltitle` field into `title`;
- Drop the `crossref`/`xref` field from the `@article` entries;
- Add a `shortjournal` field (with `EP` as content) to the `@article` entries (Note: This field is *not* used by the standard styles shipping with `biblatex`);
- Use the `\AtEveryCitekey` macro to locally replace the content of the `journaltitle` field with that of the `shortjournal` field.

Note: The following example is meant to be compiled with `pdfLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \savefield{shortjournal}{\temptitle}%
  \restorefield{journaltitle}{\temptitle}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Episkepsis1971:36,
title = {La Commission préparatoire},
journaltitle = {Episkepsis},
shortjournal = {EP},
date = {1971},
number = {36},
pages = {2},
}
@Article{Episkepsis1971:36_2,
title = {Communique de la Commission},
journaltitle = {Episkepsis},
shortjournal = {EP},
date = {1971},
number = {36},
pages = {8--9},
}
@Article{Episkepsis1972:54,
title = {La première Conférence},
journaltitle = {Episkepsis},
shortjournal = {EP},
date = {1972},
number = {54},
pages = {2--5},
}
@Collection{Episkepsis,
title = {Episkepsis},
date = {1970/},
shorthand = {EP},
keywords = {primary},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{Episkepsis1971:36}.

\printshorthands

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources principaux}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources secondaires}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no words - IT'S JUST GREAT!!! If you will allow me, I would like to ask you how to add the same function for @Inproceedings and @Proceedings. And the other one: in the other entries with shorthands in footnotes appears "(henceforth cited as NAME OF SHORTHAND)" at the end of bib-entry's data. Is there a possibility to put this text at first time citing of the bib-source according with your example or just completely suppress it? The example you gave above is really great. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @filokalos: Maybe I'll come up with something, but at the moment I have no idea. (It took me also quite some time to find a solution to your original question.) Just one thing: I'm not sure if your/my use of `@collection` was appropriate -- another possibility is `@periodical`.

Comment: It's ok, I can wait. Anyway, you already gave an answer which really helped a lot. Thank you one more time.